# At what point in development is a new system tag added?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

With Paizo's announcement of Pathfinder v2 play-testing commencing, it got me thinking.

When do/should we make tags for new game systems? As soon as its announced, so people have a tag to use? When the content is actually in playtest? Not until its publicly available? Something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A tag actually can't even exist until there's a question on the subject, so in all likelihood, that means when playtest actually begins.

For [reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6554/revisiting-whether-dd-next-needs-its-own-separate-tag) we discovered after the D&D 5e playtest, that tag should also be something *separate* from whatever tag the non-playtest published edition is eventually tagged with. (It turns out that too many questions on playtest material simply don't match the later game enough to share tags, since they're effectively different rulesets. And it's easier and less confusing to searchers to update still-relevant questions to the non-playtest tag as we find them, than the other way around.)

So in practice, it will have to be when the first question is asked, and the tag name should be something like [pathfinder-v2-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-v2-playtest) or something like that (playtest game's working name + `-playtest`), much like our [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) tag.

Answer (score 16):

We make the tag when we need the tag. Which is to say, when someone asks a question about it.

Comment: +1 We can't actually *have* the tag before this stage either, because tags only exist as long as they're attached to at least one question. Tags associated with no questions get cleaned up around midnight UTC daily.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that particular house cleaning function. Makes sense.

Comment: does that mean we can bring back the [tag:tiny-hut] tag?

Comment: @goodguy5 probably not -- see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7520/1204

Comment: @doppelgreener noted. I'll just have to make an RPG called "Tiny Hut", then we're back in business. ;)